# bootstrap styled alerts from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Is it possible to create a bootstrap styled alert instead of the standard javascript alert? I have seen plugins like data-confirm-modal in rails that allow the confirm dialog to be styled instead of the standard javascript alert. However, I want to make every javascript alert in my app's code to be styled with bootstrap - is that possible? Either a dropin replacement like `bootstrap_alert("Hello");` instead of `alert("Hello");` or a way to style the default alert dialog with some bootstrap styles would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using rails, and the data-confirm-modal gem, I can use it from javascript as described here (from the [docs](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal)):

Given an element with data-confirm attributes in place, such as

```
<a id="foo" href="#" data-confirm="Really do this?" data-commit="Do it" data-cancel="Not really"/>
```

you can invoke .confirmModal() on it:

```
$('#foo').confirmModal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a div, style it as you desire and then make a bootstrap_alert js function that makes that div visible when called and dissapear when you click "Ok!" or whatever button you want into your alert.